# Can Spree allow me to have 'Vendors' in my e-commerce app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

Rather than the typical one store app, where I (as a user) go and add products that one seller (the owner of the Spree app) is selling, what I want to do is to create an ecommerce site that has multiple vendors.

So you could see an overview of all vendors, and then you can buy multiple products from multiple vendors.

Does Spree allow me to customize it to that extent?

If so, are there any docs for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, I've done this customization exactly.  Unfortunately, that code is not available for release.  However, if you have any specific questions I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Well do you mind pointing me to any docs that may help me with this? Working within Rails Engines can be so confusing because they have their own proprietary way of doing things - and Spree seems to be the King of that. Any specific links you can give me to get me going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

E.g. For starters, how do I go about thinking about it. Would I have to create a new model called 'Vendor' - how would I do that within Spree. I obviously can't just do `rails g model Vendor`. I don't know what associations to setup, because my `app/models` folder is empty.

Comment: So any advice on how to proceed - even from a high level perspective - or links to specific areas of the guide that will help me achieve what I want, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach (the one I used), is to add a 'vendor' Property to each item.  Note - this approach assumes that each item is only sold by a single vendor.  If you actually have a marketplace with various vendors competing to sell the same item, you'll need to do a similar thing by adding a 'vendor' OptionType, that is defined for each product Variant.

Each vendor (new model) is assigned a code that can be used when setting up your items (as either a property value, or multiple variant option values).  When an order is placed, you can use a new OrderFulfillment model to track the various shipments that the various vendors will use to fulfill that order (one OrderFulfillment record per vendor in the order).

That's basically all the model changes you'll need.  In the controller area, you'll need to modify the 'shopping cart' event machine sequence to handle the different vendor's shipping methods.  And in the case of multiple vendors, you'll also need to present the user with a choice of vendor (think amazon marketplace).

How you handle your payments to various vendors was not part of my project, but shouldn't be too complex to add if needed.

Regarding links:  You should be familiar with the basic Spree concepts which are discussed in the [guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/) in general, and more specifically [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/products_and_variants.html).  You will also need to make some internal modifications (new associations, modified controller behavior) which you can read about [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/logic_customization.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options available for that.

Essentially, you want an e commerce app where users can sign up and list their own products, and then have a user profile page where someone can look and see just that user's products, right? Some people call this multi-tenancy, and if you do a google search you will soon find this spree extension: [multi-tenant](https://github.com/stefansenk/spree_multi_tenant)

I am looking to do the same thing as you, and I'm a bit wary of multi tenant because I would have to roll back to Spree 2-2 stable (I'm currently on 2-3).

The previous answer here suggests that you should create a new model called Vendor. I would say why not just update your already existing user model to become a vendor?

What I'm suggesting is simply creating an association between the User model and the Spree::Products model. This way you can scope products to individual users and create profile pages without the complexity of adding new, foreign models and/or different admins for each user. All of the spree methods are already attached to your User class, so I would think a simple belongs_to/has_many association would work. Haven't tested this at all, but that's what my thinking is.

Comment: Update: this gem did the trick for me: https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship. I'm now using Spree as a multi tenant solution and it works great.